# How to install java and .Net progmatically on windows?

Tags: automation, installation

I am looking for ways to automatically install java JDK and .Net version on Windows VM. One of the solutions I have found is

https://chocolatey.org/

Other I have found is using silent installer but I am exploring other ways. My initial approach was to use docker but the requirement is as such that I need to install it on VM

Answer (score 0):

I installed it using silent install through batch file

Comment: How did you install .NET silently?